# unir 2 bases con join en R

Tags: r, join

Tengo 2 bases de datos: **HRFINAL (con 5.759 observaciones y 103 columnas) y SMFINAL (con 510 observaciones y 33 columnas)**. Necesito combinar las bases para analizar las fechas y horas y región en el que se realizó la encuesta. En HRFINAL la variable **visfecha** me indica en qué fecha y hora se realizó la encuesta. En tanto la variable **Rgn** me indica la región en donde se hizo la encuesta. Intenté unirlas y/o relacionarlas con la variable interview_id (pues ambas bases tienen esta variable) pero los casos se me duplican ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que intentaste lo siguiente:

```
library(dplyr)

HRFINAL %>% left_join(SMFINAL ,by = "interview_id ")
```

y obtuviste duplicados.

lo mas probable es que en la base SMFINAL la variable por la cual quieres hacer join
tiene duplicados, esto lo puedes comprobar con:

```
table(duplicated(SMFINAL$interview_id))
```

Una posible solución es eliminar los duplicados de esa variable haciendo lo siguiente:

```
SMFINAL = SMFINAL %>% distinct(interview_id , .keep_all = T)
```

y luego volver a hacer el join:

```
HRFINAL_SMFINAL  = HRFINAL %>% left_join(SMFINAL ,by = "interview_id ")
```